# Updating the Biztalk assemblies without removing/undeploying the dependent ports which uses it

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, btdf, btstask

I am trying to add a resource using the BTSTASK command line and it works fine.

```
BTSTASK.EXE  AddResource -Type:BizTalkAssembly /Source:dllpath  /ApplicationName:myapp /Options:GacOnAdd,GacOnImport,GacOnInstall /Overwrite
```

But when the Biztalk assembly such as pipeline has the been used in some other application it won't work unless the port which uses this pipeline is being removed. If i remove the port from the application which uses this pipeline and then using BTSTASK i can add the resource. How this can be easily handled without removing the port of other dependent application.

Comment: Possibly you need to look at  side by side deployment.  Change the assembly version number of the DLL, deploy it, then update the port to use the new version.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the change, if no external "interfaces" on the assembly have changed, just internal implementation changes, you can sometimes get away with a simple re-GAC of the DLL.  If you've added or removed ports on an orchestration, etc. then you have to re-import into BizTalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The Artifact, Pipeline in your case, is in use and essentially 'locked'.

"been used in some other application" - You should never share artifacts between Applications.  Doing so just created this otherwise unnecessary problem.  Create a Pipeline in the local Application/Solution.

Using a tool such as BizTalk Deployment Framework, you can just redepoy the entire app taking typically just a few minutes.  Almost the same as deploying single Assembly.

Comment: ok. I am using BTDF for some application. So if i use BTDF can i handle this dependency issue easily? How does BTDF help here

Comment: For clarity, the solution is to not have any dependencies at all.  Every Solution/Application should be completely self-contained.  No references, ever.  Using BTDF let's you quickly deploy the entire app making it not much different than deploying a single Assembly.